# Laravel session not updating on production server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a page view counter in laravel 5.2. It works when I am hosting locally but I just deployed onto a server using Vultr and now it appears that sessions are not updating. I am using files to store the sessions and I can see that the files are being created.

Here is my code

```
    $viewed = Session::get('viewed', []);
    if (!in_array($id, $viewed))
    {
        Event::fire(new ViewPostEvent($post));
        $request->session()->push('viewed', $post->id);
    }
```

When i host locally I can refresh without the view counter going up but I just checked my database on my server and it updates on every refresh I make on the live server. The permissions on the storage folder is 777.

Answer (score 1):

On the production server, it's never recommended to give `777 permission`. You can give `755 permission` for storage folder. The next thing to check is the ownership of the folder.

Please change the user group to the following

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/larvel/storage/framework/sessions
```

Then run the following command from your laravel root folder.

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

After that, run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Reload your apache/nginx server using

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

It should work now.

Comment: I gave this a shot and it did not work. I changed the session driver to cookie from file and I'm still getting the same issue so I don't think it is related to the storage of the session

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my end, I was checking the user id instead of the post id so it was not finding it in the session.